# Dicht antonym - what is it?

Tags: translation, antonym

> Der Nebel wird so dicht, dass ich das Haus kaum noch sehe.

What is the antonym of "dicht" in the sense/meaning used above?

Also what about these two below?
"thick atmosphere"
"thick substance"

What is the antonym of thick here? If we want it in German of course...

Comment: There are several antonyms depending on context: leicht, lose, locker, einfach, dünn or undicht.

Comment: Oder nüchtern. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would use [*dünn*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/d%C3%BCnn) as an antonym of *dicht* (or *dick*) in the sense desired:

> - Der Nebel ist heute *dünner* als gestern.
> - In der *dünnen* Atmosphäre kann man kaum noch atmen.
> - Die Mischung ist noch viel zu *dünn*.

As mentioned elsewhere, *lichter Nebel* is also appropriate, especially, when *dichter Nebel* was ment to have the connotation *blickdicht* (being opaque), like in your example sentence

> Der Nebel wird so *(**blick**)dicht*, dass ich das Haus kaum noch sehe.

This, however, does not invalidate the existence of the phrase *dünner Nebel*. It occurs where the property opacity is not as important as the property denseness, for example, in the definition of [*Nebelschleier*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Nebelschleier) in the DWDS.

Comment: Judging from these 3 examples... I think this is exactly the word I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: *Nebel* is *lichter* not *dünner*.

Comment: @Olafant, zur Behauptung, dass Nebel nicht dünn sein könne, siehe die Bedeutung von _Nebelschleier_ im DWDS: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Nebelschleier

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Auch ein dünner Schleier kann blickdicht sein. Ist er das nicht, handelt es sich um einen lichten Schleier.

Comment: @Olafant What about if we use it for atmosphere and substance? Ist "duenn" OK there?

Comment: @peter.petrov I'd say yes. It's more about the physical property *density* or *concentration* there. But for the *Nebel* in your question it's about *das Haus kaum noch sehen*. That *dicht* is kind of a *blickdicht*, not so much about the ratio water/air.

Comment: @Olafant I see, thanks a lot! All clear now.

Answer (score 15):

This depends indeed heavily on context. In this case (fog = Nebel) you would usually say *leichter Nebel* (light fog).
*Dünner Nebel* (thin fog) would also be possible, but rather unusual.

"Dicht" is also used in the meaning of (air/water-)tight (nothing can leak out), in this case the antonym would simply be *undicht*.
Finally(?) "dicht" can also mean "close" in the context when speaking about traffic and (not) coming to close to the car in front of you ("Fahr nicht zu dicht auf"). The opposite here would be expressed as "halte Abstand" (keep distance) or "bleib weiter weg" (stay farther away).

Comment: You forgot the antonym "nüchtern" <-> "dicht" (= "sternhagelvoll"). ;-)

Comment: @Alexander that's why the question mark is there after "finally" ;-) - However, this meaning is a *very* colloquial one...

Comment: "dicht" is also colloquially used to mean "buried in work, not available for appointments". Also can mean "shut/shuttered" (both out of hours, or permanently) referring to a business or public building. There is a risk for misunderstanding "Vergiss es, der Chef ist heute völlig dicht." (intended meaning: Don't bother, the boss is too busy today. Easily misunderstood as "Don't bother, the boss is completely drunk today."

Comment: @rackandboneman Never heard that use, so I would definitely be amongst the persons misunderstanding it - or at least be very confused.

Comment: In many cases, "leck" can replace "undicht" (as in der Tank ist leck/leckt = the tank is leaky/leaking).

Answer (score 15):

Slightly old-fashioned would be:

> lichter Nebel

I don't know which meaning of [*licht*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/licht) this usage is based on: *bright* or *sparse*.

> ein lichter Morgen (*bright*)
>
> ein lichter Wald, lichtes Haar (*sparse*)

Comment: I don't think it's old-fashioned at all. *Lichter Nebel* is perfectly fine and the right expression instead of *dünner Nebel* (new-fashioned?).

Comment: Cp *to leak*, "die Heizung leckt", which directly contrasts "dicht". It could also compare to "Lichtung", which, to me, is as dark and obscure as the woods. Cue several puns about to miss the forest for the trees.

Comment: @vectory Uhm what?

Comment: @Olafant it does not make immediate sense to compare *leck* and *dicht*, I know, but the radiator is either *dicht* or it does *leck-* (Ein schlechter Witz: Warum sitzt die Blondine auf der Heizung? Weil die Heizung leckt!). cp further *[Ab-]Dichtung*, *Lichtung* and *Dickicht*!

Comment: this implies a sense development involving *shiny*, *letting shine through*, *not so dense*, *not heavy*, *thin* etc. in any order. This leaves me highly confused. Also cp Lat *levo*, En *leave, let*, G *lassen*, *durch lassen*, *erleichtern*, and *eine Sperre aufheben* (viz *levo*?)

Comment: Also contrast *Laubwald* (?) vs *Schwarzwald* "... an older general term for coniferous forests.", that is, *Nadelwälder*, hard to pass, *Laubwälder*, easy to pass, for a naive antonymy. cp perhaps *Schwarte* (crust, bacon), and of course *schwer* vs *leicht*. Also see *leicht* "easy". I'm not sure whether these idioms are Germanic, or older.

Comment: @vectory Manchmal lässt sich erahnen, welch wunderbare und höchst interessante Antworten du schreiben könntest, würdest du deine Gedanken doch bloß mal in verständlichen Fließtext gießen statt sie in telegrammstilartige Kommentare zu stückeln.